# Is this Bayes Theorem?

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

Is this Bayes Theorem?

I'm reading [this blog](https://gaoyuetianc.github.io/blogs/post/mpo/) and it says this is Bayes Theorem. I thought Bayes Theorem just had two probabilities divided by one probability.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's just Bayes theorem with some additional probability rules applied (and then some additional manipulations).

e.g. one such rule being used is $p(z,\theta) = p(z|\theta)\, p(\theta)$, which follows from the definition of conditional probability. See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#As_an_axiom_of_probability

You might start with $p(z|y,\theta)=p(y|z,\theta)\, p(z,\theta)/p(y,\theta)$ and then apply common probability rules.

If it is not immediately clear that this expression is just Bayes, begin with:
$p(z|y,\theta)\, p(y,\theta) = p(z,y,\theta) = p(y|z,\theta)\, p(z,\theta)$ (which follows from conditional probability axioms) and divide through by $p(y,\theta)$, in similar fashion to deriving the most basic form of Bayes' theorem.

Then proceed to apply simple manipulations using basic facts as needed.

Comment: Thank you. I know I can infer it from the equations, but what does the comma mean here exactly? How is it different from the | symbol? $p(z|y,\theta)$

Comment: When you're dealing with the joint distribution of more than one variable you put commas between the variables -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Densities_associated_with_multiple_variables  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Continuous_case, compare that with the use of the vertical bar in conditional distributions, with the thing after $|$ being what is conditioned on -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Conditional_continuous_distributions